# iPhone Application for Email Address Shortcut

Tags: keyboard, iphone

Does anybody know of an iPhone application or shortcut that allows you to save your email address access it via a shortcut?  This would be super useful when filling in forms in Safari or in when your email address is required in an application.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent application for shortcuts is Smile Software's [TextExpander touch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textexpander/id326180690?mt=8). Because of limitations in iOS, it doesn't work to expand shortcuts in every app (including, sadly, all of Apple's apps). From the manufacturer's [site](http://www.smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/touch/index.html):

> Given the current feature set of the
>   iPhone OS, TextExpander touch cannot
>   work in the background (as it does in
>   Mac OS X), expanding text snippets
>   while you work in other apps, except
>   for apps with TextExpander-integration
>   built-in. You must first compose your
>   text in the TextExpander touch Compose
>   screen, and then transfer it to
>   another app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to jailbreak, Action Menu does what you are looking for. I have put my e-mail address in the favorites tab of that program and I can now reach it anywhere.

Comment: I'd advice for Action Menu as well. And I doubt there's any software able to do the request without jailbreaking.